# The attitude to have in relation to issues that are perhaps provocations or attempts to turn in derision

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I see something not very pleasant in questions. I think that I am not alone in this case. I don't know if it is judicious to answer and if this is useful. Some questions seem as attempt of inter-religious disputation as to the Middle Ages. Some questions are against practicing Jews. Does someone have a guideline?

Answer (score 4):

You haven't provided any specific examples in your question, so I will just attempt to answer it in a general sense. If a post contains language that is offensive, you can downvote it and flag it as "rude or abusive." If there is no real question being asked, you can also vote to close (or flag if your reputation is below 3000) as "unclear what you're asking." These are the steps I would take in that situation. Of course, your votes are your own and you are welcome to use your own judgement.

Comment: And if a question seeks discussion instead of posing an answerable question, that would be "primarily opinion-based" (another close reason).

Comment: An example is [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68879/how-to-understand-the-texts-that-litterally-speak-of-other-gods-and-compares-to/68880#68880) that I have transformed and a sarcastic comment that was skipped. It is strange, the question and the intention are separated. To respond the question may enhance Knowledge, but engage a discussion with someone that is" Lekanter" is not right "אף אתה הקהה את שיניו". I am perplex.